# Why more charges normally accumulate at the position with a larger curvature on a curved surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors, coulombs-law

For a curved interface between two adjacent poorly conducting materials with different electrical properties, when applying a DC voltage difference between the two materials, as in a capacitor, the **free charges** will accumulate at the interface. The distribution of the charges is interesting. In general, more charges accumulate at the position with a larger curvature on a curved surface, as highlighted by red circles in the figure below.

[image]

If one plots the charge density along the interface, there will be 2 cups in the charge-density curve.
Can anyone please explain this phenomenon with basic knowledge of electrostatics?

Comment: short qualitative answer. Charge distribution tends to the minimum energy configuration. If a system has large curvature at extreme points, charges accumulate there, since larger distance means lower energy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it needs clarification in what sense *more charges normally accumulate* in this or that region: are you talking about the fraction of the total (induced?) charge? Or the charge density? If the former, how do you define the border of these regions? Has this been stated as a fact anywhere (reference)?

Comment: @RogerVadim please see my update, many thank!

Comment: @Community please see my update, many thank!

Comment: Maybe : the electric field lines will be perpendicular to the surface if it is a conductor. Thrn we know div E is propto charge density. Since a bigger curvature means a greater derivative, the charge will be higher..(?)

Answer (score 0):

Charges sit on the surface of a conductor. Microscopically, though, of course they don't overlap perfectly with the atoms of the conductor itself, and they will venture slightly outside of the edge of the surface so that they can spread away from each other more, while nonetheless being nearby the atoms of the conductor. For a curved surface, therefore, the radius of curvature of the area that the charges inhabit will be slightly larger than the radius of curvature of the conductor itself. This allows for more charge to be spread evenly despite having the same conductor surface area. Here is a simple drawing to demonstrate:

[image]